# Unable to display image from MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, image-uploading

I have a Products_Images table which stores the images in BLOB format. I want to show all the images and product details in 'View All Products' page. To accomplish this task I have created the following program, but its not giving me the desired output. Kindly check it.

Thanks.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$query=         "select distinct product_id, image from product_images";

$query_run=     mysql_query($query);

while ($query_fetch=    mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
 {




     echo '</br>';
     echo $query_fetch['image'];


 }

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");





?>
```

**Displaying The Image**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<br />
<img src="all_images.php" alt="Image" width="50" height="50" />
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: done, but still no change in the result

Answer (score 1):

When you are using  `header()` function you cannot print anything prior to a header call as this directs the web server to prepare a content header

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$query=         "select distinct product_id, image from product_images";

$query_run=     mysql_query($query);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
while ($query_fetch=    mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
 {




    // echo '</br>';
     echo $query_fetch['image'];


 }

?>
```

> Note: Please avoid using mysql*  they are depreciated in php newer
>   version keep your hands on using PDO or at least mysqli

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my code, now its not showing me the binary data,but its still not showing me the image, although its showing a blank image portion in both files.

Answer (score 0):

why you store it in database, store your image in a folder and enter the name in the database, while calling the image in the src just write the path of the folder and php code where you mention the name.

```
<img src="yourfolder/<?php echo your database table field name where images names are stored?>" />
```